# convert std::string to nsstring issue

Tags: c++, objective-c

Hi 
I use the following to convert `std::string` to NSString but it return (null)  while trying to display the value of the nsstring

I need it to return instead of (null) empty at conversion time any suggestion

```
StudyDate=[NSString stringWithCString:studyDate length:strlen(studyDate)];
```

any suggestion to avoid null values

best regards

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to have variables only differ by their case (`StudyDate` vs. `studyDate`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** The syntax `@"string"` is used *only* for constructing NSString. With `std::string` you should use the standard `"string"` syntax.

```
NSString* aConstantNSString = @"foo";
const char* aConstantCString = "foo";
std::string aConstantStdString = "foo";
CFStringRef aConstantCFString = CFSTR("foo");
```

---

1. [`+stringWithCString:length:` has been deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithCString%3alength%3a) since the very early beginning of the iPhone SDK. If the string contains only ASCII characters, often you could [use `+stringWithUTF8String:` instead](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithUTF8String%3a).
2. Your method works only when `studyDate` is a C string (i.e. `const char*`), but you said you have a `std::string`. There is no method to directly convert a `std::string` into an NSString. You must use `.c_str()` to create the C string first:

   ```
   StudyDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:studyDate.c_str()];
   ```

   (But the above shouldn't be the cause you're getting `(null)` because passing a `std::string` to `+stringWithCString:length:` or even `strlen` should give a compile-time error immediately.

   ```
   'error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ in argument passing'
   ```

   So `studyDate` should already be a `const char*`. We need more context (code) to see what's going on.)

Comment: @Ali: Show how you get `studyDate`, and how you print `StudyDate`.

Comment: std::string studyDate = @"test"; StudyDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:studyDate.c_str()]; nslog(StudyDate );

Comment: @Ali: You don't need the `@` for `std::string`. Just use `std::string studyDate = "test";`.

Comment: very well it was I ind [NSString stringWithUTF8String:studyDate.c_str()];

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString objCString = @"this is my objective c string";
std::string cppString; // this is your c++ string or however you declared it blah blah blah

cppString = [objCString UTF8String];    
// this is the conversion of an NSString into a c++ string
// not sure if it will work for c strings but you can certainly try
```

thats all there is too it im afraid. all you need is just that one line of code. this was done in ios sdk 4.3 btw so im not sure if the coding will change if you appiled it elsewhere.

Comment: You've shown the opposite of what he requested. He requested converting from std::string to NSString, not NSString to std::string.